# How to get all keys ordered by key's value from jsonb postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

how to get all keys from json ordering by value of it's own key
for example: key is a just number like uuid and value is the date

i've already do this but without ordering:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products
(
    id text UNIQUE NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT crm_id_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
    materials jsonb
);
```

```
select 
  jsonb_object_keys(materials) as key,
from 
  products
WHERE 
 id = '5'
```

so i need the result table of keys, ordered by comparing their own dates (values) like:

```
select 
  jsonb_object_keys(materials) as key,
from 
  products
WHERE 
 id = '5'
ORDERED BY KEY.GETVALUE()
```

BUT ORDERED BY key.getValue() function doesnt exists in postgres how can i do ordering if it possible?

UPDATE:
I find out another solution not beter but it works too:

```
select jsonb_object_keys(materials) as keys,
       materials -> jsonb_object_keys(materials) as date
from client_material
WHERE crm_id = '5'
order by date DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exemplary data:

```
insert into products values
('5', '{"k1": "2019-05-01", "k2": "2019-04-01"}');
```

Use `jsonb_object_keys(materials)` in a lateral join so you can use resulting keys in the `order by` clause:

```
select key
from products
cross join jsonb_object_keys(materials) as key
where id = '5'
order by (materials->>key)::date;

 key 
-----
 k2
 k1
(2 rows)
```

[Working example in rextester.](https://rextester.com/XXSCZ169990)

Comment: thank you it works very good/ but i found another solution usin to columns: